# People editor control wan't show data after post back, even if I try to load it again

Tags: people-picker

I´m working on a webpart in SharePoint 2010. I´m loading some People Editor controls with usernames, but after postback they´r cleared. I´m now trying to fill them again, but it won't work. I can see when I debug it that the entities is there, but it´s not showing in the form. What´s wrong?

**Ascx:**

```
           <SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="PeopleEditorProjectManagerNetGroup" runat="server" CssClass="ms-inputuserfield" Width="400" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1" MultiSelect="false" />
<asp:Button ID="buttonEdit" runat="server" Text="Redigera" 
            CssClass="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" onclick="buttonEdit_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonOK" runat="server" Text="Spara" 
            CssClass="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" onclick="ButtonOK_Click" />
            &#160;
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Avbryt" 
            CssClass="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" onclick="ButtonCancel_Click" />
```

Code behind (it´s when I hit the edit-button the values are gone):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadProjectData();
            EditMode(false);
        }
    }
 protected void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveProjectData();
        EditMode(false);
        LoadProjectData();            
    }

    protected void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditMode(false);
    }

    protected void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditMode(true);
        LoadProjectData();

    }

    private void EditMode(bool isEditMode)
    {
        PeopleEditorProjectManagerNetGroup.Visible = isEditMode;
    }

     private void LoadProjectData()
    {

                    string projectManagerNetGroupLoginName = spWeb.GetProperty  (string.Format("DV_ProjectManagerNetGroup", SPContext.Current.Web.Name)).ToString();
                    PickerEntity entity = new PickerEntity();
                    entity.Key = projectManagerNetGroupLoginName;
                    entity = PeopleEditorProjectManagerNetGroup.ValidateEntity(entity);
                    PeopleEditorProjectManagerNetGroup.Entities.Add(entity);
                    labelProjectManagerNetGroup.Text = entity.DisplayText;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like SharePoint throughs an javascript error from entityeditor.js "null is null or not an object"... I think it has something to do with that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the LoadProjectData code slightly, and then it worked the first time I hit edit-button. But when I click cancel and then edit again, I got a javascript error (null is null or not an object), and the people editor was not filled with data.

I therefore redirect to current page on cancel and ok. It´s a work around, but it works now.

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadProjectData();
        EditMode(false);
    }
}
protected void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveProjectData();
    //Fix for SharePoint javascript error
    Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);    
}

protected void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Fix for SharePoint javascript error
     Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);   
}

protected void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EditMode(true);
    LoadProjectData();

}

private void EditMode(bool isEditMode)
{
    PeopleEditorProjectManagerNetGroup.Visible = isEditMode;
    labelProjectManagerNetGroup.Visible = !isEditMode;
}

 private void LoadProjectData()
{

                string projectManagerNetGroupLoginName = spWeb.GetProperty  (string.Format("DV_ProjectManagerNetGroup", SPContext.Current.Web.Name)).ToString();
                PickerEntity entity = new PickerEntity();
                entity.Key = projectManagerNetGroupLoginName;
                entity = PeopleEditorProjectManagerNetGroup.ValidateEntity(entity);
                System.Collections.ArrayList entityArrayList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
                entityArrayList.Add(entity);
                PeopleEditorProjectManagerNetGroup.UpdateEntities(entityArrayList);                    labelProjectManagerNetGroup.Text = entity.DisplayText;
}
```